# Panda handling year week format for processing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question? I need to process date column with the format coming like W_2022_27. How does Panda recognize the data is of %yyyy-%m format?

By reading, I am not able to understand how to read the column data as date.

Comment: What's `W` mean?

Comment: It is a String Prefix to the date value in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
df['newcol'] = d.dfate.dt.strftime('W_%Y_%W')
```

Here the week is starting on Monday, but if you want the week start on Sunday, slight modification is required:

```
df['newcol'] = d.dfate.dt.strftime('W_%Y_%U')
```

So %W means week starts on Monday, %U means week start on Sunday.